# How to add additional action buttons in a civicrm Add Event form?

Tags: civievent

I have added a button in the EventInfo.tpl

```
 <div class="crm-submit-buttons">
           <div style="display:none">{include file="CRM/common/formButtons.tpl" location="bottom"}</div>
           <span class="approved-logic crm-button crm-button-type-upload">
            <button>Approve</button>
        </span>
           <span class="request-approval crm-button crm-button-type-upload"
            <button>Request for Approval</button>

        </div>
```

But when I click on Add Event under Manage Events, I see a popup which does not 
show my button but when I click on add event and add it to new window it shows 
the button, how can I make sure it works on both the places
1) Popup 
[image]
2) New Window(which is showing currently)
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

First think its not a good practice to over-ride any core files specially templates when you can use jQuery to play around.

You can use buildform() hook to add button(s) to a form and the pop up window will recognise the button based on class or attribute and append it on popup form

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Thanks @Pradeep, can you provide an example or link of adding button via buildform hook and also of how popup will recognise a class

Comment: Hi , how to add buttons using buildForm() ?

Comment: You will need to over-ride the button to include existing + new button through buildform. The other option is to add button using smarty in tpl file using below snippet

{crmButton p='civicrm/request' q="action=browse&reset=1&gid=$gid" icon="th-list"}{ts}Request for Approval{/ts}{/crmButton}

Comment: What does q in the above html means? {crmButton p='civicrm/request' q="action=browse&reset=1&gid=$gid" icon="th-list"}{ts}Request for Approval{/ts}{/crmButton} , I need to add redirection to current page as my url added in 'p' is 'event-workflow/request'